# Switch screens (libgdx) - Game class implementing ApplicationListener

Tags: java, android, libgdx

We are working on a game with libgdx and we want to be able to switch screens.
I have made a GameOverScreen, which implements Screen:

```
public class GameOverScreen implements Screen {
}
```

My problem is that i don't know how to set the screen in my main class. Most of the examples i have looked at shows a main class which extends Game (com.badlogic.gdx.Game). But our main class implements ApplicationListener and doesn't extends Game:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {
}
```

Therefore i can't use the setScreen method from the Game class. So how can i change the screen in my main class Game?

Comment: I did the same as done in com.baclogic.gdx.Game. I found an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41818768/7061548 and here: http://book2s.com/java/src/package/com/badlogic/gdx/game.html

Answer (score 1):

com.badlogic.gdx.Game does nothing else but also implement ApplicationListener. There are some simple options:

- So you could just extend com.badlogic.gdx.Game instead of implementing ApplicationListener
- Do the same as com.badlogic.gdx.Game does. For example:

  ```
  public void setScreen (Screen screen) {
      if (this.screen != null) this.screen.hide();
      this.screen = screen;
      if (this.screen != null) {
          this.screen.show();
          this.screen.resize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
      }
  }
  ```
- Use Composition / Adapter: Create a field of com.badlogic.gdx.Game in your ApplicationListener implementing class and delegate the methods you implement.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all `Game` is predefined class so use different class name instead of `Game` for your own implementation.
- `com.badlogic.gdx.Game` is nothing more than `ApplicationListener`, it has only a reference of `Screen` so having `setScreen()` method.
- Extend your `Main(origin)` class with `Game` instead of writing own implementation because you need `Screen` transition in your game.

Some Rules of SE :

- **Never Write the Same Code Twice.**
- **Don't use hand to break a brick if already you've hammer.**

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you need 3 classes

- ScreenManager Class
- Abstract Screen Class (Optional)
- ScreenEnum (Enum)

Play screen and main menu screen will be extended from Abstract screen.
Screenmanager switches the screen according to screen code from screenenum

****Screen Enum Class****

```
public enum ScreenEnum {
    MAIN_MENU {

        public AbstractScreen getScreen(Object... params) {
            return new MainMenuScreen();
        }
    },
    PLAY {

        public AbstractScreen getScreen(Object... params) {
            return new PlayScreen();
        }
    };
    public abstract AbstractScreen getScreen(Object... params);
}
```

**ScreenManager Class**

```
public class ScreenManager {

    private static ScreenManager instance;

    private Game game;

    private ScreenManager() {
        super();
    }

    public static ScreenManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ScreenManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void initialize(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
    public void showScreen(ScreenEnum screenEnum, Object... params) {
        Screen currentScreen = game.getScreen();

        AbstractScreen newScreen = screenEnum.getScreen(params);

        newScreen.buildStage();
        game.setScreen(newScreen);

        // Dispose previous screen
        if (currentScreen != null) {
            currentScreen.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstarctScreen Class  (Optional class)**

```
public abstract class AbstractScreen implements Screen {

    protected AbstractScreen() {
        super( );
    }
    public abstract void buildStage();

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height){
    }

    @Override public void hide() {}
    @Override public void pause() {}
    @Override public void resume() {}
}
```

---

**Screen Switch**

```
ScreenManager.getInstance().showScreen(ScreenEnum.PLAY, 0);

ScreenManager.getInstance().showScreen(ScreenEnum.MAIN_MENU, 0);
```